# Access C++ non-POD class data from naked asm function

Tags: c++, assembly

Is it possible to make this mixed c++/asm function to be standard-compliant?
Function ePendSV() must have this layout:

```
ePendSV: //function entry point
    mrs r0,PSP
    stmdb r0!,{r4-r11,lr}
// compiler can generate any code here doing these things:
    readyTcbQueue.pTcb.runTcb->psp = r0;
    readyTcbQueue.pTcb.runTcb=readyTcbQueue.pTcb.readyTcb;
    r0 = readyTcbQueue.pTcb.readyTcb->psp;
// work with r0 in assembly
    ldmia r0!,{r4-r11,lr}
    msr PSP,r0
    bx lr
```

**readyTcbQueue.pTcb** is a simple struct object with just two pointers to **BragOsTcb** objects;

```
struct{
    BragOsTcb *runTcb;
    BragOsTcb *readyTcb;
};
```

**BragOsTcb** is non-POD class but without virtual functions and virtual inheritance and looks like this:

```
class BragOsTcb : public TcbCdllq, public TimerTcbCdllq, public BragOsObject{
public:
    BragOsTcb();
....
private:
.....
public:
    unsigned long psp;
....
};
```

**TcbCdllq, TimerTcbCdllq, BragOsObject** are also simple classes with similar layout and without virtuals. But they are also non-POD.

I've made this code it works on gcc and clang but it's a nonstandard hack and might not work.

```
__attribute__((naked)) void ePendSV(){
  asm volatile("\
    mrs r0,PSP \n\
    stmdb r0!,{r4-r11,lr} \n\
\n\
    ldr r1,=%0 \n\
    ldmia r1,{r2,r3}  // r2=runTcb, r3=readyTcb \n\
    str r0,[r2,%1] // save psp \n\
    str r3,[r1,#0] // runTcb=readyTcb \n\
    ldr r0,[r3,%1] // readyTcb->psp \n\
\n\
   // restore LR(EXC_RETURN),R11-R4 from new PSP, set new PSP, return \n\
    ldmia r0!,{r4-r11,lr} \n\
    msr PSP,r0 \n\
    bx lr \n\
    "   :
        : "i"(&readyTcbQueue.pTcb),"i"(&(((BragOsTcb*)0)->psp))
        : );
    // it'is an offsetof hack which might not work
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is hardly plausible that the ofsset of psp will change in runtime. Why are you worried? Is it a library that will be used in different cmpilers from the one you use?

Comment: Yes, this is a library and it can be used on different compilers. offset of psp wont change in runtime. but it can be changed from compiler to compiler or can be treated as error by some compilers. i had another implementation of this function with more than one asm keywords. that function was discarded by clang-3.7 with an error message but worked on clang-3.5 and gcc-4.8. I can do runtime check to be sure offsetof psp is correct: `if( (long)(&readyTcbQueue.pTcb->psp)
  != ((long)readyTcbQueue.pTcb + (long)(&(((BragOsTcb*)0)->psp))) ){
   unrecoverableError("....");
 }`

Comment: Will ePendSV be called from outside your library? If so than it's in itself a problem since the naked attribute is compiler specific. But if it is an internal function then you can add a short asm clause that loads the addresses for you into the required registers befor calling the function

Comment: ePendSV will never be called from code, it is an interrupt handler and will be called by hardware. In this function i must change stack pointer to different location by hand so it is naked function. I can call normal C++ static function from ePendSV which will access class members in usual way by it's not so good because i need maximum performance here, code runs on embedded system

Comment: I see your point. It is hard to say what kind of trouble you will get into. Maybe the best way would be to change BragOsTcb. I will post an answer with what I have in mind

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is to access the psp member of BragOsTcb from a naked function that can have no arguments and further more it is called from as a hardware interrupt handler so you can't add any other code to load the address for you.
BragOsTcb is non POD so you are afraid that the psp member offset from the beginning of the class will be different for different compilers.

I would suggest the following scheme:

```
struct BragOsTcbWrapper
{
    BragOsTcb* this_;
    unsigned long psp;
};

struct{
    BragOsTcbWrapper *runTcb;
    BragOsTcbWrapper *readyTcb;
};

class BragOsTcb : public TcbCdllq, public TimerTcbCdllq, public BragOsObject{
public:
    BragOsTcb()
    : pspHolder({this,0})
    {

    }
....
private:
.....
public:
    BragOsTcbWrapper pspHolder;
....
};
```

Now for the asemblly you will do:

```
__attribute__((naked)) void ePendSV(){
  asm volatile("\
    mrs r0,PSP \n\
    stmdb r0!,{r4-r11,lr} \n\
\n\
    ldr r1,=%0 \n\
    ldmia r1,{r2,r3}  // r2=runTcb, r3=readyTcb \n\
    str r0,[r2,%1] // save psp \n\
    str r3,[r1,#0] // runTcb=readyTcb \n\
    ldr r0,[r3,%1] // readyTcb->psp \n\
\n\
   // restore LR(EXC_RETURN),R11-R4 from new PSP, set new PSP, return \n\
    ldmia r0!,{r4-r11,lr} \n\
    msr PSP,r0 \n\
    bx lr \n\
    "   :
        : "i"(&readyTcbQueue.pTcb),"i"(&(((BragOsTcbWrapper*)0)->psp))
        : );
}
```

I think this will work for you

Comment: Thanks for answer. Nice solution. I'll post another solution without additional pointers but costs single jump instruction

Answer (score 0):

Since extended asm in naked function is not supported by gcc/clang

> naked
>       This attribute allows the compiler to construct the requisite function declaration, while allowing the body of the function to be
>   assembly code. The specified function will not have prologue/epilogue
>   sequences generated by the compiler. Only basic asm statements can
>   safely be included in naked functions (see Basic Asm). While using
>   extended asm or a mixture of basic asm and C code may appear to work,
>   they cannot be depended upon to work reliably and are not supported.
>   https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html#ARM-Function-Attributes

We can use normal C++ function and jump/call it from naked

```
typedef unsigned long U32;

__attribute__((naked)) void ePendSV(){
    asm volatile("\
        mrs r0, PSP \n\
        stmdb r0!, {r4-r11,lr} \n\
        b realSwitchContext"); // this solution costs single jump instruction named **b**. It's valid for ARM-assembly in this case.
                              // Stack pointer has been saved in r0 register. we dont care about stack for now.
}

extern "C" void realSwitchContext(U32 psp){
    readyTcbQueue.pTcb.runTcb->psp = psp;
    BragOsTcb *tcb = readyTcbQueue.pTcb.readyTcb;
    readyTcbQueue.pTcb.runTcb = tcb;
    psp = tcb->psp;
    asm volatile("\
        ldmia %0!, {r4-r11,lr} \n\
        msr PSP, %0 \n\
        bx lr" : : "r"(psp)); // we just changed stack pointer then can return here and don't care about C++ stacked data
}
```

There is some bug in implementation above because of two stack pointers - MSP and PSP. MSP will be corrupted by last `bx lr` instruction if C++ will use the stack. Solution below is correct but costs 2 'expensive' instructions - bl (call) and bx lr (return)

```
__attribute__((naked)) void ePendSV(){
    asm volatile("\
        mrs r0, PSP \n\
        stmdb r0!, {r4-r11,lr} \n\
        bl realSwitchContext \n\
        ldmia r0!, {r4-r11,lr} \n\
        msr PSP, r0 \n\
        bx lr");
}

extern "C" U32 realSwitchContext(U32 psp){
    readyTcbQueue.pTcb.runTcb->psp = psp;
    BragOsTcb *tcb = readyTcbQueue.pTcb.readyTcb;
    readyTcbQueue.pTcb.runTcb = tcb;
    return tcb->psp;
}
```

Comment: It looks appealing. However I think you may leave the stack in an undefined state. The compiler generates code that stores things on the stack inside realSwitchContext and since you switch the stack pointer you leave the previous stack with all sorts of data on it. Also the stack pointer itself is changed by the compiler generated code. I don't think you can rely on this to be a good solution (Unless of course you make sure you always keep the correct stack pointer)

Comment: Initial stack pointer saved by first instruction mrs r0, PSP. r0 is an first argument for realSwitchContext named psp then it will be saved into C++ object. Compiler can alter stack (PSP) freely(after mrs r0,PSP of course) because it will be restored later by msr PSP, %0 (%0 is psp read from another C++ object) in another call ePendSV. bx lr (return from function instruction) placed exactly after restoring stack pointer instr. so compiler cannot change stack ptr here too.

Comment: Sorry i was mistaken. There are two stacks PSP and MSP. Registers saved in asm saved to PSP stack. But C++ will work with MSP. Correct way is to call rather than jump and move all asm code to ePendSV which costs single call instruction and single return one.